# Download Excel File via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to download a file from IBM Cognos via Excel VBA. The script will execute, but I only get a 9KB Excel file that will not open. How do I make this work?
Here is my code:

```
Sub ado_stream()
'add a reference to Microsoft XML v6 and MS ActiveX Data Objects
'via Tools/References
'This assumes the workbook is saved already, and that you want the file in the same folder
Dim fileStream As ADODB.Stream
Dim xmlHTTP As MSXML2.xmlHTTP
Dim strURL As String

strURL = "http://foo.bar"

Set xmlHTTP = New MSXML2.xmlHTTP
xmlHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False, "username", "password"
xmlHTTP.Send

If xmlHTTP.status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "File not found"
    GoTo exitsub
End If

Set fileStream = New ADODB.Stream
With fileStream
    .Open
    .Type = adTypeBinary
    .Write xmlHTTP.responseBody
    .Position = 0
    .SaveToFile "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\Test.xlsx"
    .Close
End With

exitsub:
Set fileStream = Nothing
Set xmlHTTP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: try ` xmlHTTP.responseText`

Comment: Before you open the stream, you should probably use  loop to check for `xmlHTTP.ReadyState = 4`  - with a `DoEvents` - and even a short `Sleep` call afterwards to make sure the document has fully loaded

Comment: @cyboashu, change .responseBody to .responseText yeilds "Arguments are of thw wrong type..." error msg.

Comment: @dbmitch, it reads .ReadyState = 4 immediately. Any other ideas?

Comment: What status is returned - there's no redirect?

Comment: @dbmitch, MsgBox xmlHTTP.readyState yeilds 4; MsgBox xmlHTTP.status yeilds 200

Comment: Why are you setting `.Position = 0`? Doesn't that reset the file pointer back to the beginning?

Comment: @dbmitch, that is from the original code.

Comment: What _original_ code? It doesn't make sense to me - unless you're going to start reading from the top instead of writing the file. Have you tried it without?

Comment: @dbmitch, the original code I took from the internet. I commented out that line and got the same result.

Comment: What do you get from `xmlHTTP.getResponseHeader ("Content-Length")`? Does it change if you add a `DoEvents` and `Sleep 2000` before you open your stream? Add to module above all functions `Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`

Comment: MsgBox xmlHTTP.getResponseHeader("Content-Length") yields a blank box. Did not change with DoEvents and Sleep 2000.

Comment: One guess, can you open the downloaded file in notepad? Is the content readable? If yes can you post top 10-15 lines or so, If that doesn't contain any sensitive data.

Comment: @cyboashu, its the login screen. It says my password was wrong. I was able to login with IE with the same UN and PW. `    IE.document.getElementById("CAMUsername").Value = "UN"
    IE.document.getElementById("CAMPassword").Value = "PW"
    IE.document.getElementById("cmdOK").Click` What should I do?

Comment: is your actual URL,`http` or `https`?

Answer (score 1):

try sending the password via auth header. see if that works.

```
 Set xmlHTTP = New MSXML2.xmlHTTP
    xmlHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64
    xmlHTTP.Send

'EncodeBase Function. Put your actual user name and password here.
Private Function EncodeBase64() As String
    Dim arrData() As Byte
    arrData = StrConv("<<username>>" & ":" & "<<password>>", vbFromUnicode)

    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    EncodeBase64 = objNode.text

    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: `StrConv("<<username>>" & ":" & "<<password>>", vbFromUnicode)` yeilds error message 'Error parsing '????????????' as bin.base64 datatype. What should I do?

Comment: <<username>, put your username which you use to login into the website. same for password.

Comment: I did and I tried with and without the << >>. Same error. Do I need to add a reference?

Comment: i didn't get an error but I got the same 9KB file as the result

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I read throught the 9KB file some more and I believe it is asking me for a third input. I'm going to do more research into in it.